# TPL Dataflow - very fast producer, not so fast consumers OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, .net, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow

I'm experimenting with TPL Dataflow before porting it into my production code.
The production code is a classical producer/consumer system - producer(s) produce messages (related to financial domain), consumers process those messages.

What I'm interested in, is how stable environment will stay if at some point producer(s) produce much more faster than consumers can handle it (will system blow up, or what will happen) & more importantly what to do in those cases.

So in attempt to have similar simple application I come up with following.

```
var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<Item>();

var executiondataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                        ,
    BoundedCapacity = 100000
};

var dataFlowLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions
{
    PropagateCompletion = true
};

var actionBlock1 = new ActionBlock<Item>(t => ProcessItem(t),
    executiondataflowBlockOptions);

bufferBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock1, dataFlowLinkOptions);
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    bufferBlock.SendAsync(GenerateItem());
}

bufferBlock.Complete();
Console.ReadLine();
```

`Item` is a very simple class

```
internal class Item
{
    public Item(string itemId)
    {
        ItemId = itemId;
    }

    public string ItemId { get; }
}
```

`GenerateItem` simply news up `Item`

```
static Item GenerateItem()
{
   return new Item(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

Now, to imitate *not so fast* consumer - I made `ProcessItem` to hold for `100ms`.

```
static async Task ProcessItem(Item item)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing #{item.ItemId} item.");
}
```

Executing this results in OOM exception in 20 or so seconds.

Then I went on and added more consumers (more ActionBlocks up to 10), which wins some more time, but eventually results in the same OOM exception.

I also noticed that GC is under huge pressure (VS 2015 Diagnostics tool shows GC is running almost all the time), so I introduced object pooling (very simple one, essentially it is `ConcurrentBag` storing items) for `Item`, but still I'm hitting the same wall (OOM exception is thrown).

To give some details on what is in memory, why it is running out of it.

- Biggest size have objects of type `SingleProducerSingleConsumerQueue+Segment<TplDataFlow.Item>` & `ConcurrentQueue+Segment<TplDataFlow.Item>`
- I see that `BufferBlock`'s InputBuffer is full of `Item`s (Count=14,562,296)
- Since I setup `BoundedCapacity` for `ActionBlock`(s), their input buffer is also close to the configurated number (InputCount=99,996)

To make sure that slower producer would make it possible for consumers to *keep up*, I made producer to sleep between iterations :

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
    bufferBlock.SendAsync(GenerateItem());
}
```

And it works fine - no exception is thrown, memory usage is constantly low, I don't see any GC pressure anymore.

So I have few **questions**

1. Am I doing anything inherently wrong while trying to reproduce very fast producer/slow consumer(s) scenario with TPL Dataflow building blocks
2. Is there any way to make this work and not fail with OOM exception.
3. Any comments/links on best practices how to handle this kind of scenarios (very fast producer/slow consumers) within TPL Dataflow context.
4. My understanding of the problem is - since consumers can't keep up, `BufferBlock`'s internal buffer is getting filled with messages very fast, and holds off to messages until some of the consumers come back to ask for next message as a result application runs out of memory (due to filled up internal buffer of `BufferBlock`) - would you agree with this ?

I'm using `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` package -version 4.5.24.
.NET 4.5 (C# 6). Process is 32 bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've identified the problem nicely: the `BufferBlock` is filling its input buffer until it hits OOM.

To solve this, you should add a `BoundedCapacity` option to your buffer block as well. This will throttle producers automatically for you (no need for the `Thread.Sleep` in your producer).

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! Would you comment on the behavior of `BoundedCapacity` of BufferBlock. In particular once internal buffer is full what's going to happen with incoming messages? Are they going to be dropped? (at the moment that seems to be the case). Do you maybe have this covered in more details in your book Stephen ?

Comment: @Michael: Messages are never dropped. If you `Post` a message to a full block, it will return `false` (indicating the message was not accepted). If you `await SendAsync` a message to a full block, it will (asynchronously) wait for there to be room and then post the message. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13605979/263693).

Answer (score 2):

There is a potentially serious problem with the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    bufferBlock.SendAsync(GenerateItem()); // Don't do this!
}
```

The [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync) method returns a `Task`, which can be a much heavier object memory-wise than the actual item you are sending to the block. In the specific example the returned task is always completed, because the `BufferBlock` has unbounded capacity, and so the memory footprint of the task is practically zero (the same cached `Task<bool>` instance is returned all the time). But after configuring the block with a small [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) value, things will quickly get interesting (in an unpleasant way). Each call to `SendAsync` will soon start returning an incomplete `Task`, different each time, with a memory footprint of around 200 bytes per task (300 bytes if the `CancellationToken` parameter is also used). This will obviously not going to scale well.

The solution is to use the `SendAsync` the way it is intended to be used. Which means it should be awaited:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    await bufferBlock.SendAsync(GenerateItem()); // It's OK now
}
```

This way the producer will be asynchronously blocked until there is available room inside the block to accommodate the sent item. Which is hopefully what you want. Otherwise, if you don't want to block the producer, don't use the asynchronous `SendAsync` method, and use the synchronous [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) method instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    var item = GenerateItem();
    while (true)
    {
        bool accepted = bufferBlock.Post(item); // Synchronous call
        if (accepted) break; // Break the inner loop
        if (bufferBlock.Completion.IsCompleted) return; // Break both loops

        // Here do other things for a while, before retrying to post the item
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the lower lever [`OfferMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.itargetblock-1.offermessage) method (instead of the `Post` or the `SendAsync`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    var item = GenerateItem();
    while (true)
    {
        var offerResult = ((ITargetBlock<Item>)bufferBlock).OfferMessage(
            new DataflowMessageHeader(1L), item, null, false);
        if (offerResult == DataflowMessageStatus.Accepted) break;
        if (offerResult == DataflowMessageStatus.DecliningPermanently) return;

        // Here do other things for a while, before retrying to offer the item
    }
}
```

The magic number `1L` is a value declared internally in the TPL Dataflow [source code](https://source.dot.net/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Internal/Common.cs.html#72cc16e34836a856), denoting:

> A well-known message ID for code that will send exactly one message, or where the exact message ID is not important.