# How to process a complete list of inputs with TPL Dataflow?

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I'm new to TPL Dataflow and I have it working but I am not sure if I'm using it properly. I have a list of inputs (strings) and I want to process them (all) with a max degree of parallelism and know when it's all complete. Right now I just `foreach` through the inputs and call `Post` on the `ActionBlock`, ignoring the return value. This seems incorrect since it could miss inputs.

My question is: how do I avoid missing items? Is there a built-in block to which I can just give my inputs and it will make sure they are all attempted? (Regardless of success/failure per input.)

The suggestions I've seen basically amount to:

```
await block.Completion;
```

Does this account for failed inputs (where `Post` or `SendAsync` would return false)? The strange thing for me is that it seems like this determination is made when I call `Post` and not after, so this `Completion` wouldn't even include those items.

I feel like I need basically a retry loop for the inputs that it wasn't able to handle the previous time around, something similar to:

```
while (items.Count > 0) {
  foreach (var item in items) {
    if (await block.SendAsync(item)) {
      items.Remove(item);
    }
  }

  await block.Completion;
}

block.Complete();
```

(Except with better loop handling/error checking.)

Is this additional level unnecessary? Or am I wrong conceptually somewhere?

Comment: Related: [TPL Dataflow, whats the functional difference between Post() and SendAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599305/tpl-dataflow-whats-the-functional-difference-between-post-and-sendasync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems incorrect since it could miss inputs.

Assuming you're using the defaults, this is correct. `Post` only returns `false` if the block refuses the input. This can happen if the block has received a `Complete` signal, or if the block's input buffer is full. By default, each block's input buffer can grow indefinitely, so an `ActionBlock` with a default input buffer size will only return `false` from `Post` after `Complete` is called.

The most common use case for `ActionBlock` is with an [unlimited bounded capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) and where the code only calls `Complete` after all items have been added. In that case, `Post` will never return `false` and you can safely ignore the return value.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Post` will return false if the block is completed, or if the block's input buffer is full. Since the setting [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) is not something exotic, and may well become required in a later stage of a project to solve emerging problems with high RAM usage, I don't think it's a safe bet to use the `Post` method and simply ignore the result. To be protected from unfunny bugs involving missing messages (that could be orders or invoices), you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var accepted = block.Post(item);
    if (!accepted) throw new InvalidOperationException("Item was not accepted");
}
```

This way you'll at least be notified that something is broken, and won't let buggy behavior to creep in.

On the other hand awaiting [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync) and ignoring the result is much safer. The `SendAsync` will normally return `false` in conditions where an exception has happened or a cancellation has occurred, in which case you'll get notified at the point you `await` for the `Completion` of the block. So no need to throw exceptions in this case.

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    await block.SendAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

For performance reasons you could use both `Post` and `SendAsync`. This will make a difference only if you have tens of millions of items to process.

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (!block.Post(item))
    {
        await block.SendAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```